# How do I display custom formatted nested keys in swimlane ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, ngx-datatable

```
<ngx-datatable
   [rows]="services"
   [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

I can get this to display nested data with:

```
{ prop: order.product.price }
```

How do you do you display a custom calculation in a row?
What if I want to apply a fee to the price

```
{ prop: 'order.product.price + order.fee' }
```

I guess I would need access to the other values in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-template`. For example:

```
     <ngx-datatable-column name="Order Price+Fee">
        <ng-template let-row="order" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <div>{{order.product.price + order.fee}}</div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
```

I did not test your specific code, But this is one way to do it. Try it and adopt as your requirements

For more info:

[Official Documentation templateref](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#templateref)

[Official Code example](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/templates/template-obj.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ngx datatable seems to be limited with it's prop field in that it doesn't take calculations. I personally got around this by taking advantage of the [Typescript accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). In your case it would be something like

```
get priceAndFee() { return this.product.price + this.fee; }

... prop="order.priceAndFee" ...
```

If you think that's cumbersome, that would make two of us.